# Sensenet: Supports Mysql or Not

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, sensenet

I have tried Sensenet with SQL Server but I can not configure it through Mysql

Does Sensenet support Mysql DB too? Please help me how to configure Mysql in Sensenet?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the [built-in database provider](https://github.com/SenseNet/sensenet/tree/master/src/Storage/Data/SqlClient) for sensenet supports SQL Server only. There are a few syntax differences between MySql and SQL Server so it is not possible to use the built-in data provider for MySql - but you can take the code and scripts (see the link above) and try to convert them to MySql. Then you can configure this new custom provider as the metadata provider in sensenet.

It is not a simple task as there are many stored procedures and inline scripts (mainly in *SqlProvider.cs*) but it is doable. In the future we plan to simplify the data provider interface and support more db providers out of the box.